# Fire simulation, flame height

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

I'm making a simulation of two fireballs, I've tweaked every setting to my liking and the flame looks pretty good (as in, close to what I want it to be) with 32 divisions as resolution as that's what I used to work, the problem I have is that when I increase the resolution to bake it and make it look crisp, the flames get much much taller. Even at 64 they get a good 50% taller.

How can I get good quality flames without them increasing in height?

EDIT: Blend file added as per request: [image]

EDIT2: Okay, the actual problem is not the height, it looks taller because it's skinier but it's not actually taller, what I need to do is increase the width of the flame without it getting taller. [image: Here] I outlined the flame with the grease pencil at 32 (black) and 128 (red) divisions and you can see what I mean.

Comment: It's strange. Could you upload your blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? There are couple of options to reduce flame height but I don't know wich will suits you.

Comment: I added the .blend file, I think it's because with 32 resolution most of the more subtle bits of the flame are not there but when I increase it to 64 or 128 they are much more aparent.

Comment: It's ok here. Go to Front Ortho View, bake simulation at 32, mark highest flame with cursor, then change it to 64 and bake. For me it's the same height.

Comment: Sorry for taking some time, my baking times are not as great as I'd like. So I just did what you said and I just realized that the problem is not actually the height but the width. It being much skinnier at higher resolutions makes it look stretched out! [here](http://puu.sh/twMWy/3fdd1a63f3.jpg) I outlined the flame with the grease pencil in 32 (black) and 128 (red) divisions and you can totally see what I mean. Can I increase the width of the flame without it resulting in the flame going higher up?

Comment: First of all you can just stretch emitter on the X axis. Secondly you can play with Temp Diff, Speed and Flame Rate (it's emitter properties, not domain).

Comment: Okay I've managed to tweak it now by increasing the size of the icospheres and tweaking the speed and temp diff, thank you very much for your help!